# Почему signatures == null?

Tags: android, java

Добрый вечер!
Я использую следующий код:

```
PackageInfo info = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(absolute_apk_name, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        if (info != null)
        {
            Signature[] sig = info.signatures;
            if (sig != null)
                sigstring = new String(sig[0].toChars());
        }
```

Но `info.signatures == null`, и у меня нет идей почему
Файл ***absolute apk name*** существует, я это проверял
Android 2.1

```
absolute_apk_name = "/data/data/ru.UseIT.SimpleFormsLauncher/files/SimpleFormsGeneral.apk"
```

apk создается с флагами `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE|Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`

И если выполнить этот код

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(absolute_apk_name )), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

То все устанавливается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А Вы в логах видите подобное :

```
W/PackageParser(65468): Skipping dir: /data/data/com.exemple/files/YourApp.apk
```

то есть путь в "data" игнорируется - качайте Ваше приложение в общедоступный каталог

странно только что выдаёт эту ошибку такая проверка (source code android.content.pm.PackageParser):

```
mArchiveSourcePath = sourceFile.getPath();
         if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
             Slog.w(TAG, "Skipping dir: " + mArchiveSourcePath);
             mParseError = PackageManager.INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK;
             return null;
         }
```

Comment: Хм, странно, потому что установка то возможна :)
Раз уж на то пошло, подскажите такой общедоступный каталог, не на флешке, и getExternalStorageDirectory() не подойдет, так как флешки в устройстве не будет, и андроид там 2.1